# Get json from wikipedia page data

Tags: json, mediawiki, converters

I need to convert [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_band_name_etymologies) Wikipedia page data to *JSON* in the following form

```
{
 "band1": "desc1",
 "band2": "desc2",
 "band3": "desc3",
 ...
}
```

I found out that [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) won't help me, are there any suggestions?

Comment: "Wikipedia page data" is mostly raw. You will have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did it just with CTRL + F in Atom and RegEx :d